# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Veriton L460 with AR5001 wifi card

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm going to try and set up wifi on a computer with Ubuntu installed where it doesn't work out of the box.  The computer is an Acer Veriton L460 with a AR5001 wifi card.  There are two options as far as I know:

1. Use MadWifi
2. Use ndiswrapper

There are steps for using Madwifi here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305514

Some hints for ndiswrapper are here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-240280.html.
The driver seems to be available here: http://www.netgate.com/support/Drivers/STA_24071bin/Install/.

So my questions are, are there any other types of ways to do this?  Are there any positives and negatives for chosing MadWifi or ndiswrapper?  Has anyone had success installing this particular wifi card in ubuntu, and if so what did you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of Ubuntu, the built-in `ath5k` driver should kick in and work. If it doesn't, it might be getting locked out by older `ath` drivers.

[Click here to see how to block the old drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Atheros).

`ath5k` will generally deliver better results than `madwifi`. And `madwifi` is better than `ndiswrapper` IMO.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Oli says, the kernel team maintains newer versions of wireless drivers for you, which could provide better support. You can access them by installing the `linux-backports-modules-lucid` package.